# Un-checking the "Wrap JDBC Objects" in Payara5 gives error

Tags: java, jdbc, mysql-connector, payara

In Payara 5.201 application server, I am trying to un-check "**`Wrap JDBC Objects`**" in JDBC Connection Pools -> Advanced for MySQL database pool.

[image: Wrap_JDBC_Objects_screen_shot]

But I am getting the following error when I save it.

```
An error has occurred 

Could not apply changes: Could not change the attributes: Constraints for this JdbcConnectionPool configuration have been violated: on property [ ] violation reason [ Statement Wrapping should be set to true before performing this operation ]
```

[image: Error Screen Shot]

By default this property comes as checked in, due to that I am getting the following error in my application and the provided solution is to uncheck the "Wrap JDBC Objects" in Payara server.

```
com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ProfiledConnectionWrapper40 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

I tried creating a new Connection but during that I am not getting this property to check / unchecked.

My connection details is as below and I am using the "**mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar**" and MySQL version is "**5.7.22**"

[image: Payara_Connection_Details]